# Does Odoo implement oauth2 for its API?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to implement an Odoo API to provide a web service to another system. I am using [RESTFUL API For Odoo](http://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/restful/) to expose a rest API instead of XML-RPC API.
This module generates a token for authentication, but I don't know if this token is enough to secure for authentication.
I would like to know how to implement OAuth 2 to improve security in this module or to know if Odoo already includes OAuth 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth2 is implemented already as an official module, see [https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/auth_oauth/**manifest**.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/auth_oauth/__manifest__.py)